# Angular + RxJs + Webpack not treeshaking RxJs operators and observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, rxjs

first of all, I would like to say I´ve tried to study a lot of threads and topics about this problem and none of suggested solutions worked.

Problem if that `source-map-explorer` in my `Angular 11.2.2` project using `RxJs 6.6.7` and `Webpack 4.42.1` tells me that RxJs bundle contains a lot of operators **I do not use in my app**. For example `mergeAll` which is not used anywhere in my project. The same thing happens for "observable package", where I can see functionalities I do not use

[image: The result of RxJs bundle]

Additional info:

- The versions of all libraries are relative up to date as seen above
- `compilerOptions.module` is set to `esnext` (es2015,es2016,es2020 did not work either)
- clean npm install was performed
- there is no import * from rxjs or import from rxjs (or anything like that). Operators are imported separately from `rxjs/operators`

**Does anyone have a clue why I have bundled operators and other RxJs functionality that I do not use?** Is, for example, possible that Angular internaly uses these functionalities and therefore webpack bundles them together?

Comment: Hard to say only with this. I would create a new angular app to make sure the treeshaking works well.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell. Many operators in RxJS are implemented as combination of other operators so for example `mergeAll()` is used by `concatAll()`. `concatAll()` is then used by `concat()`. `concat()` is then used by `startWith()` and I think it's very likely that you're using `startWith()` in your project.